# preg_match_all spaces with fullstops regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am writing some unit tests for some methods I am using, and have found a weird bug and would like some Regex advice.

when doing:-

```
$needle = ' ';
$haystack = 'hello world. this is a unit test.';
$pattern = '/\b' . $needle . '\b/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $haystack, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)
```

I'm expecting the positions to positions found to be

```
[5, 12, 17, 20, 22, 27]
```

The same as if I did this, to get none exact whole word matches

```
while (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset)) !== false) {
   $offset = $pos + 1;
   $positions[] = $pos;
}
```

However the preg_match_all does not find the 2nd occurrence (12) the space between

```
. this
```

Is this to do with the \b boundary flag? How can I resolve this to make sure it picks up other this?

Thanks

Comment: How can you expect `\b \b` to match space between `.` and `this` if you require a word char on both sides? What word boundary do you need? What is a "word" for you? A space cannot be word in any logical world.

Comment: Hi Wikto -  I wasn't! That's why I was writing the tests, and wanted to know how to handle it correctly. My code is working for words, but I want to update it to handle if its passed as space =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `$pattern` in `preg_match_all()` like below:-

```
<?php
$haystack = 'hello world. this is a unit test.';
while (($pos = strpos($haystack, ' ', $offset)) !== false) {
   $offset = $pos + 1;
   $positions[] = $pos;
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($positions);

preg_match_all('/\s/', $haystack, $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

echo "<pre/>";print_r($matches);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/725574

Note:- you need to use `\s` for checking white-spaces

You can apply an `if-else` to change `$pattern` based on `$needle`:-

```
if($needle == ''){
   $pattern = '/\s/';
}else{
   $pattern = '/\b' . $needle . '\b/';
}
```

Comment: Brill, thank you Anant - works perfect. Tests are all green now! =)

Comment: @OnIIcE  glad to help you. :):)